# "__count_memcg_events undefined" while make

Tags: debian, kernel-modules, make

Using Debian Bullseye (testing) on 5.2.0-3.
Try to compile ncpfs-module.
I try to compile a module which worked fine til 5.2.0-2. But if I try to "make" under 5.2.0-3 I got:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.2.0-3-amd64'
  CC [M]  /tmp/ncpfs-module/dir.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/ncpfs-module/file.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/ncpfs-module/inode.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/ncpfs-module/ioctl.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/ncpfs-module/mmap.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/ncpfs-module/ncplib_kernel.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/ncpfs-module/sock.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/ncpfs-module/ncpsign_kernel.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/ncpfs-module/getopt.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/ncpfs-module/symlink.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/ncpfs-module/ncpfs.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
ERROR: "__count_memcg_events" [/tmp/ncpfs-module/ncpfs.ko] undefined!
make[4]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.2.0-3-common/scripts/Makefile.modpost:91: __modpost] Fehler 1
make[3]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.2.0-3-common/Makefile:1614: modules] Fehler 2
make[2]: *** [Makefile:179: sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:8: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.2.0-3-amd64'
make: *** [Makefile:49: all] Error 2
```

I can't find any like count_memcg inside the code of my module. Maybe something in Debian Bullseye is *broken* ?

Comment: Please run the `make` command again but setting your locale first so we can read the error messages: `LC_ALL=C make`. Also, it might be worth running a `make clean` first in case you have remnants from a previous build.

Comment: There don’t seem to be any `__count_memcg_events` changes between the Debian packages of 5.2.9 and 5.2.17. Which version of `ncpfs` are you building?

Comment: @StephenKitt : Don't know about 5.2.9 or 5.2.17 - my Debian is on 5.2.0-3! I try to make my own fork https://github.com/EnzephaloN/ncpfs-module , because there is no other maintained module for newer kernels.

Comment: Looking at the messages, the problem is that `__count_memcg_events` is **not** defined, the compiles and the link complete. Perhaps https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10866005/ which defines the function (to be empty) would help?

Comment: 5.2.9 is the last version of the 5.2.0-2 package, 5.2.17 the first version of the 5.2.0-3 package (see [the Debian package tracker](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/linux) for details.

Comment: @icarus that patch is included in all versions of 5.2 in Debian (but yes, it would have been plausible).

Comment: Did you build your 5.2.0-2 kernel yourself? I can’t get `ncpfs` to build with any released Debian package of the 5.2 kernel.

Comment: It worked for me with 5.2.0-2 from Debian repository without problems. Some others are using my ncpfs with 5.3.7 in Suse or other dists.